# PhalconPHP - getRouter in \Phalcon\Di

Tags: php, phpstorm, phalcon

I've created new project using PhalconPHP 3.1.2. Everything works fine, but I have problem with IDE. In PhpStorm I've added `ide/stubs/Phalcon` from phalcon-devtools 3.1.2 as external libraries to dispose of warnings and errors.

But there is still one problem: in `app/config/router.php` (standard catalog structure created by devtools) I got line `$router = $di->getRouter();` (also created by devtools) with warning: `Method getRouter not found in Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault`.

There is no method in this class indeed: https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools/blob/3.1.x/ide/stubs/Phalcon/di/FactoryDefault.php -> https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools/blob/3.1.x/ide/stubs/Phalcon/Di.php

Now I don't have autocomplete of router's methods and this is problem for me. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First of all -- I'm not familiar with Phalcon. These are my comments based on general PHP/PhpStorm experience.

So .. if you look at that PHPDoc in the last link you gave ([stubs for Di.php](https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools/blob/3.1.x/ide/stubs/Phalcon/Di.php)) you will notice the code example there that has `$request = $di->getRequest();`.

If you just copy-paste that whole sample you will get the same "method not found" error ... as `getRquest()` is transformed at run time via magic `__get()` method.

The possible solution here is to create your own stub for your `$di`:

1. Create new class that will extend original `Di`, e.g.

   ```
   class MyDi extends \Phalcon\Di
   ```
2. Add all those `getRoute()` / `getRequest()` etc methods there (could be real methods with empty bodies as in Phalcon's stub files .. or via `@method` PHPDoc tag)
3. Place such file anywhere in the project -- it will be used by IDE only.
4. When you are using your `$di` -- typehint it with your class, e.g.

   ```
   /** @var \MyDi $di */
   $di = new Di();
   ```

   In the above code during runtime `$di` will be an instance of `Di` but for PhpStorm during development it will be `MyDi` so all type hints are in place.

---

As possible alternative -- instead of using magic via `$di->getRoute()` .. try `$di->getShared('route')` or similar.

If you use [PhpStorm's Advanced Metadata functionality](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata) it will allow to get correct type based on parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

`$di->getRouter()` is magic method, `Phalcon\Di` implements `__call` method and it gets router service this way if you use `getRouter()`.

If you want you can use PHPStorm metadata and use `$di->get()` https://www.google.pl/search?client=opera&q=phpstorm+metadata&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8